# How do I find a certain link from the source code using bs4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using a get request to get the source code. I want bs4 to parse it and output the link I'm looking for.
Heres the source hmtl

```
</form>
<div class="cart-actions">
<div class="cart-actions__checkout-buttons js-cart-actions--bottom">
<form action="https://www.google?dwcont=C315063094" method="post" name="dwfrm_cart_d0afivhtybaj" novalidate>
```

```
import requests
import html.parser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
  'authority': 'www.google.co.uk',
  'accept': '*/*',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin'
  }




with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.google.com'
    atcurl = 'https:/google.com'
    bagurl = 'https://'google.com'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    csrf_token = soup.find('input',{"name":"csrf_token"})["value"]
    atc = {
    'format': 'ajax',
    'Quantity': '1',
    'pid': '466040871206',
    'csrf_token': csrf_token 
    }
    r = s.post(atcurl, headers=headers, data=atc)
    if '<span class="bag-count">1</span>' in r.text:
        print("Added to cart")
    else:
        print("Failed adding to cart")
    r = s.get(bagurl, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

I'm looking to get the C315063094
Anyone know how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the certain link that you are referring to? Because C315063094 is nowhere related to your edit

Comment: this one from the source code https://www.google?dwcont=C315063094 but it would be better only to get the numbers

Comment: You mean to say you want all the "315063094" present in  https://www.google.com' ?

Comment: yes the google is a replacement link but when i go on "google.com" and press cntrl U and the cntrl F and type C315063094 it comes up with the source code i provided. Basically i want bs4 to do this for me when i send a get request to "google.com" and store the C315063094 as a variable

Comment: Appologies but I tried what you are saying and it gives me 0 element on searching using ctrl + F. Maybe you are trying to fetch something in particular

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "<form action="https://www.google?dwcont=C315063094" method="post" name="dwfrm_cart_d0afivhtybaj" novalidate>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
full_form = soup.find('form', attrs={'name':'dwfrm_cart_d0afivhtybaj'})
action_qparam= full_form.get('action').split("=")[1]

print(action_qparam)
```